# ReadProcessMemory : ошибка 998

Tags: winapi, память

Добрый день! Прошу помощи в вопросе чтения памяти. Я получаю структуру `MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION` о некотором регионе, который нужно прочитать. Поле `AllocationProtect` установлено в `PAGE_EXECUTE_WRITECOPY` ( то бишь читать нельзя ), а поле `Protect` установлено в `PAGE_READWRITE`. Читать мне надо именно по `BaseAddress RegionSize` байт, а не по `AllocationBase`. Тем не менее, несмотря на то, что у этого региона стоит `PAGE_READWRITE`, `ReadProcessMemory` всё равно даёт 998-ую ошибку. В чём косяк? Заранее благодарю

Вот приложил код функции.

```
 PBYTE FindAndWrite(HANDLE hProcess, PBYTE pRegionAddress, DWORD dwRegionSize, DWORD dwSignature)
    {
        //в pRegionAddress передаётся поле BaseAddress структуры MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION
        PBYTE pCurrentAddress = pRegionAddress;
        char cDebugMessage[100];
        DWORD i = 0;

        DWORD dwBuffer = 0;
        DWORD dwBytesRead = 0;

        for(i;i<dwRegionSize-4;i++)
        {
            if (!ReadProcessMemory(hProcess,pCurrentAddress,&dwBuffer,4,&dwBytesRead)
            {
                wsprintf(cDebugMessage,"Can't read some memory - Error %d",GetLastError());
                ShowError(cDebugMessage);
            }
            else
            {
             //...обработка
            }
            pCurrentAddress++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Краткий обзор интернета показал, что `::ReadProcessMemory` может вернуть `ERROR_NOACCESS`, если Вы ей передадите неправильный буфер. Поэтому, приложите, пожалуйста фрагмент кода с вызовом этой функции.

Comment: Добавил код к сообщению...